# Can't set alias within Pipenv

Tags: bash, alias, pipenv

I am using Pipenv to manage a virtual environment for a Django project. I would like to set up an alias that works within my Pipenv to perform a python command that is lengthy (and frequently used).

I tried setting up this alias by adding the following line to my .env file:

```
alias launch='python manage.py collectstatic --noinput; heroku local'
```

However, when I run my new `launch` command in my Pipenv, it is not recognized:

```
$ pipenv shell
$ launch
bash: launch: command not found
```

Is there a way to add an alias to my Pipenv .env file so that it is loaded every time I execute `pipenv shell`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.env` file is only for setting environment variables. It is not a shell script and cannot contain arbitrary commands such as `alias`.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up creating the alias by adding to my .bashrc file, which it seems is imported when I run pipenv shell.